# Getting unnecessary error and warning in eclipse when laravel project is added

Tags: eclipse, laravel-5

When i add laravel project files in eclipse, eclipse show many errors and warnings.

When same project is added in sublime , it is not flagging any error and warnings.

How can i resolve or remove these errors and warning.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a blade-plugin, you can get rid off warnings by excluding the views folder from validation settings this way :

Project Properties > Validation > check "Enable project specific settings", 
then right click "HTML syntax validator (for PHP files)" > select "Settings" > click "Add Exclude Group". Now select "Exclude Group" on the left side panel, then click "Add Rule", choose "Folder or filename" > click "Browse Folder" and then browse to "ressources/views/" folder.

In addition you can enable PHP code completion for Laravel by adding a folder in Project Properties > PHP > include path > libraries, which contains that [Laravel IDE Helper](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822).